# Pass PHP variable to Javascript code

Tags: php, javascript

I obtained a value in PHP and wanna use it in javascript.

Is there any way to do so ??

Here is the code i am using which is not working

```
$var = "abc"; 

document.getElementById(<?php echo $act;?>).class="active";
```

I am using `echo $var` inside the `getElementById` method..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code should look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("<?php echo($var); ?>").className = "active";
</script>
```

Please note that to change the "class" in JavaScript, you have to access it with the "className" property, not "class".

Comment: You could probably make it a little easier (and safer) by using json_encode(), e.g. `document.getElementById(<?php echo json_encode($var); ?>).className = "active";`.

Answer (score 1):

This should work, **if your PHP code** *(in the Javascript one)* **is placed in a `.php` file** -- which are executed by the PHP interpreted, while `.js` ones are not.

Note that you should place quotes arround the id you pass to `getElementById` :

```
document.getElementById('<?php echo $act;?>').class="active";
```

And, of course, your JS code must be placed between `<script>` tags :

```
<script type="text/javavascript">
    document.getElementById('<?php echo $act;?>').class="active";
</script>
```

Comment: It should be "className" rather than "class", btw.

Comment: Oh, didn't notice that ; here's an upvote for your answer, which is then better than mine, on that part :-)

Answer (score 1):

That is the correct usage except for one thing: `document.getElementById()` expects a string, but when you echo `$act` you get `abc` without quotes. So you need to do:

```
document.getElementById("<?php echo $act;?>").className ="active";
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that should work. But note that PHP is a pre-processor, so your code would end up as:

```
document.getElementById(abc).class="active";
```

instead of:

```
document.getElementById("abc").class="active";
```

note the missing quote. anyway, I assume you use the name correctly, in your post you declare $var but echo $act.

Comment: It should be "className" rather than "class", btw.